# xargs and cut: getting `cut` fields of a csv to bash variable

Tags: bash, cut, xargs

I am using `xargs` in conjuction with `cut` but I am unsure how to get the output of `cut` to a variable which I can pipe to use for further processing.

So, I have a text file like so:

`test.txt`:

```
/some/path/to/dir,filename.jpg
/some/path/to/dir2,filename2.jpg
...
```

I do this:

```
cat test.txt | xargs -L1 | cut -d, -f 1,2
/some/path/to/dir,filename.jpg
```

but what Id like to do is:

```
cat test.txt | xargs -L1 | cut -d, -f 1,2 | echo $1 $2
```

where $1 and $2 are `/some/path/to/dir` and `filename.jpg`

I am stumped that I cannot seem to able to achieve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to say something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r f1 f2; do
    echo ./mypgm -i "$f1" -o "$f2"
done < test.txt
```

- `IFS=, read -r f1 f2` reads a line from `test.txt` one by one,
  splits the line on a comma, then assigns the variables `f1` and `f2`
  to the fields.
- The line `echo ..` is for the demonstration purpose. Replace the
  line with your desired command using `$f1` and `$f2`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```sh
cat test.txt | awk -F, '{print $1, $2}'
```

From `man xargs`:

> xargs [-L number] [utility [argument ...]]
>
> **-L number**
> Call **utility** for every **number** non-empty lines read.

From `man awk`:

> **Awk** scans each input **file** for lines that match any of a set of patterns specified literally in **prog** or in one or more files specified as **-f progfile**.

So you don't have to use `xargs -L1` as you don't pass the `utility` to call.

Also from `man awk`:

> The **-F fs** option defines the input field separator to be the regular expression **fs**.

So `awk -F,` can replace the `cut -d,` part.

> The fields are denoted **$1**, **$2**, ..., while **$0** refers to the entire line.

So `$1` is for the first column, `$2` is for the second one.

> An action is a sequence of statements. A statement can be one of the following:
>
> print [ **expression-list** ] [ > **expression** ]
>
> An empty **expression-list** stands for **$0**.
>
> The `print` statement prints its argument on the standard output (or on a file if `> file` or `>> file` is present or on a pipe if `| cmd` is present), separated by the current output field separator, and terminated by the output record separator.

Put all these together, `cat test.txt | awk -F, '{print $1, $2}'` would achieve that you want.

Comment: this is great but I still am not able to use `$1` and `$2` for further piping operations. Maybe I am being stupid here, but say I want to process `$1` and `$2` onto another pgm as args.. so something like: `cat test.txt | awk -F, '{print $1, $2}' | ./mypgm -i $1 -o $2` how do I do this :((